# Error while Running Activity must be exorted or contain an intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, main-activity

I am getting this error while running the MainActivity or App.

[image]

Main AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <service
        android:name=".DelayedMessageService"
        android:exported="false" >

    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Android version: 2.2.2
I tried to Invalidate cache & restart, but it didn't help. Did follow few other tutorials but that didn't help either.
P.S: I am trying to execute IntentService from my MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed your activity tag too early without including intent filter in it.
Instead of `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />` try this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `intent-filter` as a child of `activity`.